# Ruby: search a string for multiple search terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I would like to do something like the following:

```
 if params[:entry].include? ("http" || "www" || "com" || "abc" || "def")
     ...
 end
```

I tried using regex but it didn't work (can't convert regex to string) and I need the statement to return true if the strings we're searching for appear **anywhere** in params[:entry].

What is the best way to do this using Ruby / Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't `params[:entry].match(/(http|www|com|abc|def)/)` do the trick?

[String pattern to regexp - String#match](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001499)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Wukerplank's answer probably you want to match these strings in any case (lower/upper), you can do this changing a bit the regexp this way:

```
params[:entry].match(/(http|www|com|abc|def)/i)
```

And of course you could use the `=~` operator instead of call match on the string if you prefer:

```
params[:entry] =~ /(http|www|com|abc|def)/i
```